# error: 400 when using google natural api to analyze entities

Tags: php, google-api

I'm using Google Natural API to analyze entities in text which I pull from DB. Everything was working fine, but suddenly it is showing me this error.

```
{ "error": { "code": 400, "message": "The language ur is not supported for entity analysis.", "status": "INVALID_ARGUMENT" } }
```

The text is simple English. May contains some links in it but nothing special. Please help me how to fix this issue.
Thanks.